# Displaying GLFW Windows in JAVA GUI

Tags: java, c++, user-interface

How can I add GLFW in JAVA Swing GUI like JFrame since I am trying to create a simple 3D/2D modeler using some JButtons? I already wrote a simple 2d + 3d model builder using OpenGL (Legacy Version) using C++ in Visual Studio 2022 and used GLFW API for displays and inputs. I know that I can create a linked library to call my renderer(C++) functions in JAVA.

Apparently I couldn't find any resources on how to do so, all I know is GLFW might only work within Visual C++ compilers but when I tried using the gcc/g++ (GNU) compilers on Visual Studio Code but no GLFW windows seems to be popping up while running the same code. I don't know whether I need to use another GUI API like OpenGUI to create it instead of JAVA GUI.

Comment: To call C/C++ stuff from inside Java is only halfway straight forward as long as this stuff is not a GUI component. The integration of GUI elements written in something else then Java requires also the integration of the GUI framework underneath that GUI component – but most of these frameworks refuse to be integrated into another.

Comment: So are you planning to use your own code with Java JNI to use GLFW in Java from scratch, or use helpful libraries like LWJGL or JOGL?

Comment: @newQOpenGLWidget  I am using my own code which is actually stored as DLL file, I am not sure what JAVA JNI is and I am not using any JAVA libraries like the ones you mentioned

Comment: 'I am using my own code which is actually stored as DLL file' ; sorry, I'm a bit flustered. Do you want to directly use that DLL, with all its functions and classes, in Java?

Comment: @newQOpenGLWidget  Yes I am directly calling the DLL files for calling the functions and classes in my JAVA code snippet, using JNA not JNI after researching what JNI I just want to know whether it is possible for GLFW to create a window while calling it in a JAVA code.